# ng-model does not get updated in IE

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

The below code sets the ng-model JUST ONCE , whereas in CHROME AND FF it works fine.

```
<form>
        <div ng-repeat="ques in $.vm.records track by $index">

            <div class="input-group">
                <select ng-model="ques.choiceid">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="{{choice.id}}" ng-repeat="choice in ques.choices track by $index" >{{ choice.text }}</option>
                </select>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

UPDATE
I am using angular version 1.4.7 and browser version is IE11

Comment: what version of IE are you checking it on? [check here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: Try to create options via "ng-options" like in docs
ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ng-options` for select dropdown in angular as shown in angular docs.
The below code works in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

     <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>

     <div class="">
       Selected id : {{selected.id}} and value : {{selected.label}}
     </div>
   </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
                     id: 1,
                     label: 'aLabel',
                     subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
                   }, {
                     id: 2,
                     label: 'bLabel',
                     subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
                  }];
    });
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```